# How to get center of the displayed area in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, frame

Set up a `UIScrollView` of height **1400** with numerous `UIButtons`. On clicking each of these `UIButtons`, i reveal a small `UIView`(hidden when view is loaded) containing some values. I want to display these `UIViews` at the **center** of the displayed area of the `UIScrollView`.

When i click **'TYPE'**(behind the UIView in the image), i reveal the view as shown below:

[image]

But no matter where **'TYPE'** button is and when clicked i want to reveal `UIView` as shown below(always at the center of the displayed area):

[image]    [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not adding this view to `self.view`? Adding to `self.view` will keep it on top of your scrollview, and center co-ordinates will be static (can be hardcoded).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
yourCustomAlert.center = self.view.center;
```

Inside your scrollView

1. first get visible Rect of scrollview

   ```
   CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(myScrollView.contentOffset.x, myScrollView.contentOffset.y, myScrollView.bounds.size.width, myScrollView.bounds.size.height)
   ```
2. then get it's center

   ```
   CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(visibleRect.size.width/2, visibleRect.size.height/2);
   ```
3. then set your alertView's center

   ```
   yourCustomAlert.center = centerPoint;
   ```

Comment: hey is this not working, if you still facing problem then update your question.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know how to get visible rectangle offset. Thanks!

Comment: CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(myScrollView.contentOffset.x, myScrollView.contentOffset.y, myScrollView.contentOffset.x + myScrollView.bounds.size.width, myScrollView.contentOffset.y + myScrollView.bounds.size.height) should be CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(myScrollView.contentOffset.x, myScrollView.contentOffset.y, myScrollView.bounds.size.width, myScrollView.bounds.size.height)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not clear as much. Though, if you want that your hidden view will appear on the center of the screen despite of the scrollView bounds, you can use

```
yourHiddenView.center = self.view.center; //If Parent class is a ViewController
//yourHiddenView.hidden = NO;
```

**OR**

```
yourHiddenView.center = self.center; //If Parent class is a UIView
//yourHiddenView.hidden = NO;
```

And, if you want the hidden view to be at the center of `ScrollView` find the *visible rect* of the `scrollView` and find its *center*

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;

CGPoint scrollViewCenter = CGPointMake(visibleRect.size.width/2, visibleRect.size.height/2);

yourHiddenView.center = scrollViewCenter;
//yourHiddenView.hidden = NO;
```